# find a char array in another char array in c

Tags: c++, strchr

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char name[10];
    cin>>name;
    char str[] = "Thomas";
    char * pch;
    pch=strchr(name,str);
    if (pch!=NULL) {
        cout<<"Foud"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hello, why i can't use 2 variables in strchr function, if you know how to search words in string

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps you are looking at the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: why is this tagged C++ when it is using mostly the C way of doing things? either use `std::string` or remove cout and use C, but don't try ugly mixing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[strstr](http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/strstr.htm)**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char name[10];
    cin>>name;
    char str[] = "Thomas";
    char * pch;
    pch=strstr(name,str);
    if (pch!=NULL) {
        cout<<"Found"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to strchr is a character, expressed as an int. It will find the first instance of that character in the string.

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

If you want to find a substring in a string use strstr,

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

strstr will point to the first substring or NULL if it's not found.

Answer (score 1):

`strchr` is used to `Locate first occurrence of character in string`. `strstr` is used for `Locate substring`. See the references:

- [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/)
- [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)

So, your program should look like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char name[10];
    cin>>name;
    char str[] = "Thomas";
    char *pch = strstr(name,str);
    if (pch != NULL) {
        cout<<"Found"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```